# This class is not key value coding-compliant with @IBInspectable

Tags: ios, swift

I created a @**IBDesignable** on a custom view to set a property from IB. But i get this class is **not key value coding-compliant** despite i have that attribute in my class.

```
@IBDesignable class ExclusiveSelectorView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cellWidth: CGFloat?
}
```

Failed to set (cellWidth) user defined inspected property on (Test.ExclusiveSelectorView): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cellWidth.

[image]

And this is my class
[image]

Comment: That screen shot that shows the custom class bit, is that for the view or for the file owner?

Comment: You might need to explicitly define the setter and getter methods for the variable, check out this site http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: Seems if i leave a default value without a setter/getter also works, so i'll keep in this way! So basically @IBInspectable var cellWidth: CGFloat = 0 instead of an optional.

Comment: Might also try `@IBInspectable var cellWidth: CGFloat!`, but don't fix it if it isn't broke.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot define primitives as nullable for `@IBInspectable`s.

When you attempt to do so, and set the value for one of these properties, you'll get the following warning at IBDesignable time:

> @IBDesignable class TestDesignable
>    IB Designables: Ignoring user defined runtime attribute for key path "testInt" on instance of "TestDesignable". Hit an exception when attempting to set its value: [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key testInt.

And at runtime, you'll get the following error:

> Failed to set (testInt) user defined inspected property on (TestDesignable): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key testInt.

To fix it, change it from an optional to non-optional, and give it some zero default value.

Invalid:

```
@IBDesignable class TestDesignable: UIView {
  @IBInspectable var testInt: Int? = nil // crash
  @IBInspectable var testFloat: CGFloat? = nil // crash
  @IBInspectable var testPoint: CGPoint? = nil // crash
  @IBInspectable var testColor: UIColor? = nil
}
```

Valid:

```
@IBDesignable class TestDesignable: UIView {
  @IBInspectable var testInt: Int = 0
  @IBInspectable var testFloat: CGFloat = 0
  @IBInspectable var testPoint: CGPoint = .zero
  @IBInspectable var testColor: UIColor? = nil
}
```

Comment: Why  `@IBInspectable var testColor: UIColor? = nil` can be nil? If at the beginning you said: "You cannot define primitives as nullable for @IBInspectables."

Comment: @Santiagocarmonagonzález People usually denote "value types" as primitives. `UIColor` is a reference type, it can be `nil`. In short, designables must be representable in Obj-C and in Obj-C only reference types can be `nil`.

Comment: I would give you 100-million points for making this super-blunt for me. I've encountered this "bug" in almost every project I've undertaken since swift came out. thanks!

Comment: I am getting the `IBDesignable time` warning even after intitializing the primitive types.